# Forcing eclipse indexer to always use specific header file when opening declaration

Tags: c, eclipse, declaration, indexer

I've got a very huge C project that is meant to be built on Solaris. I use a Windows PC for most of my work, ssh'ing into a solaris box when I need to make edits and build the code.

I've recently imported the project into Eclipse (Luna) on my Windows machine from GitHub for ease of traversing the code. One problem I'm having is that the indexer cannot seem to determine which header file a particular declaration is coming from... I mean it's not able to tell that an enum in alarm.c can be found in alarm.h (as alarm.h is included in alarm.c), because that same enum (ERROR, for example) can be found in a couple other header files in another part of the project. See the image for what happens when I press F3 on one of the enums with multiple declarations in the project:

[image]

Is there a way to force the indexer to always use alarm.h when it has anything to do with alarm.c source code? Can I have it ignore the rest of the project? It would really aide in getting rid of the thousands of "errors" in the project which are specifically related to "multiple declarations found" by the indexer.

Comment: you might try only defining the value in one place, probably in a .c file, and have the header files `extern` that definition

Comment: I'd like a solution that does not require changing any code

Comment: The 'complete me' operation depends on the 'tags' file and the tags file will have every tag defined in the project.   I do not know of any way to limit the 'complete me' to only look at the current file + #included header files

Comment: As a side comment: I believe you are setting yourself up for trouble by trying to attempt to use Eclipse for this particular use case (you would want to build and deploy on Solaris but actually never leave your Windows-based IDE, right ?). I'm pretty certain that NetBeans (with its [Remote C/C++ development feature](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/remotedev-tutorial.html)) will be a much better fit for you.

Comment: I'll look into that Pete, thanks